# Could NASA and Physisist use the Parker Space Probe to prove Einstein's theory that time slows down the faster one goes outside particle colliders?

Tags: time-dilation, solar-system, nasa

Einstein's theory has already been proven, but [only in particle colliders](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/einsteins-time-dilation-prediction-verified/).  But the Parker Space Probe at closest approach is approximated to reach speeds of about 430,000 mph or (~0.064% the speed of light).  Let's assume if NASA was to ask the probe its current on board system clock time, and take note of it.  After the probe is at 430,000 mph for a few minutes we then ask the probe for its on board system clock time, we also not down the time on Earth.  We then calculate the amount of time between the two requests from the perspective of Earths time.  If we were to also calculate the difference in value between the probes time value, and compare it with the amount we obtained using Earths time, would we see any difference?  If so, could we consider the Parker Space probe to be the first man made object to **noticeably** time warp (in to the future, not the past that is)?  Or is the speed of the probe to slow for any difference to be seen (difference is less than or within margin of error) for just a few minutes?

Comment: Time dilation has been tested countless times, and not only in particle accelerators. The article that you linked says an experiment tested it "with unprecedented accuracy", not for the first time ever.

Comment: It was demonstrated in 1971 [by putting an atomic clock on an aeroplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment), so the Parker Space Probe is fifty years too late to be the first to demonstrate it.

Comment: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2022AdSpR..70..842S/abstract

Comment: The existence of neutrons of solar origin are also evidence of time dilation as their rest frame lifetimes are shorter than the light transit time between the Sun and Earth.

Answer (score 3):

> Einstein's theory has already been proven, but only in particle colliders.

Not true. Relativistic time dilation has been demonstrated using atomic clocks in aeroplanes, and more recently relativistic time corrections are an essential part of the Global Positioning System - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System). So relativistic time dilation could definitely be observed in signals from the Parker Solar Probe, as long as its onboard clocks are accurate and precise enough.

What the article that you linked to actually says is that measurements of time dilation using the experimental storage ring at the [GSI Helmholtz Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSI_Helmholtz_Centre_for_Heavy_Ion_Research) are *more precise* than previous measurements.